# will there any conflict while creating temporary tables in MySql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

Will there any conflict while creating temporary tables of Same name in MySql from different Procedures simultaneously?

For Ex :-

I'm creating a temporary Table 'tblTemp' and working with that in a Procedure - procedure1,
At the Same time before completion of 'procedure1' can i create another temporary table with same name ('tblTemp') in another Procedure procedure2? 
will there any conflict?

Is this depends on the Connection - (session)

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temp tables are connection-specific